# Ruby on Rails Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I want to create the following loop in rails:

```
If value<=5 
display image1.gif value.times && display image2.gif (5-value).times
```

I was trying to add this to my View, but is there a way I can convert it into a method? How would I put the image tags if I where to make it a helper method?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `(5-value).times` - what is this?

Comment: @Codeglot, say `value = 2`, then `(5-value).times` will execute (i.e. "loop") a block attached to it 3 times (5-2). In the OP's code, it is part of pseudo code and it is not actual Ruby code. See [documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#M000187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For star rating system)
Got it working like this:

```
def display_stars content_tag :span, :class => 'stars' do
  current_admin_rating.times do 
    concat(image_tag("image1.gif";, :size => "30x30", :class => "gold")) 
  end 

  (5-current_admin_rating).times do 
    concat(image_tag("image2.gif";, :size => "30x30", :class => "gold")) 
  end 
  nil 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def show_starts(value)
  if value <= 5 
    image_tag("image1.gif")*value + image_tag("image2.gif")*(5-value)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `value` is supposed to be passed in as a parameter to the helper function, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I'm understanding what you're looking for.

Put this in a helper file:

```
def image_helper(value, image1, image2)
  html = ''

  if value <= 5
    value.times { html += image_tag(image) }
    (5 - value).times { html += image_tag(image2) }
  end

  html.html_safe
end
```

Then call it from your view like like:

```
image_helper(value, 'image1.gif', 'image2.gif')
```

Comment: Thanks.
It's actually for a star rating system. but I think I got it.
I did it like this and it seems to work:
    def display_stars
      content_tag :span, :class => 'stars' do
        current_admin_rating.times do
          concat(image_tag("http://image1.gif", :size => "30x30", :class => "gold"))
        end
        (5-current_admin_rating).times do
          concat(image_tag("http://image2.gif", :size => "30x30", :class => "gold"))
        end

        nil
      end
    end